# unordered_set storing elements as pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, equality, unordered

To narrow it down: I'm currently using [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/unordered.html). I see two possible solutions:

1. Define my own [Equality Predicates and Hash Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html) and to utilize templates (maybe `is_pointer`) to distinct between pointers and instances;
2. Simply to extend `boost::hash` by providing `hash_value(Type* const& x)` as for hashing; and add `==` operator overload as free function with `(Type* const& x, Type* const& y)` parameters as for equality checking.

I'm not sure whether both variations are actually possible, since I didn't test them. I would like to find out you handle this problem. Implementations are welcome :)

**EDIT 1:**
What about this?

```
template<class T>
struct Equals: std::binary_function<T, T, bool> {
    bool operator()(T const& left, T const& right) const {
        return left == right;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Equals<T*> : std::binary_function<T*, T*, bool> {
    bool operator()(T* const& left, T* const& right) const {
        return *left == *right;
    }
};
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've just defined:

```
friend std::size_t hash_value(Base const& base) {
    boost::hash<std::string> hash;

    return hash(base.string_);
}

friend std::size_t hash_value(Base* const& base) {
    return hash_value(*base);
}
```

And then:

```
Derived d1("x");
Derived d2("x");

unordered_set<Base*> set;

set.insert(&d1);

assert(set.find(&d2) == end());
```

Debugger says that `friend std::size_t hash_value(Base* const& base)` is never called (GCC 4.7). Why is that?

**EDIT 3:**
I found out that `template <class T> std::size_t hash_value(T* const& v)` in `boost/functional/hash.hpp` on line #215 (Boost 1.49) is Boost's specialization for pointers and it simply masks your custom implementation of `hash_value` such as mine in **EDIT 2**. 
Therefore, it seems like the only way here is to create a custom Hash Functor.

Comment: Re edit: The class templates `unary_function` and `binary_function` are deprecated. (C++11 §D.8.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the hash function, you have a choice between specializing `boost::hash` (or `std::hash` in the newer standard) or defining a new functor class. These alternatives work equally well.

For the equality operator, you need to define a new functor, because you cannot redefine the equality operator over pointers. It's a built-in operator (defined in functional terms as `bool operator==( T const *x, T const *y )`) and cannot be replaced.

Both of these can be defined generically by using a templated `operator()` in a non-templated class.

```
struct indirect_equal {
    template< typename X, typename Y >
    bool operator() ( X const &lhs, Y const &rhs )
        { return * lhs == * rhs; }
};
```

Follow a similar pattern for the hasher.

Comment: Shouldn't the template be above `indirect_equal`?

Comment: @Haroogan No, it is "a templated operator() in a non-templated class," as described. This way you don't need to manually specify the template arguments.

Comment: @Haroogan You overloaded `hash_value` in your own namespace; you did not specialize the class template `hash` in namespace `boost` as I mentioned. The `hash_value` function is a Boost extension which was not standardized and as such should be avoided. Sorry for the confusion, I've just never heard of `hash_value` before.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration all edits in the original post I would like to provide complete solution which satisfies my needs:

**1. Equality:**

```
template<class T>
struct Equal: ::std::binary_function<T, T, bool> {
    bool operator()(T const& left, T const& right) const {
        ::std::equal_to<T> equal;

        return equal(left, right);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Equal<T*> : ::std::binary_function<T*, T*, bool> {
    bool operator()(T* const & left, T* const & right) const {
        Equal<T> equal;

        return equal(*left, *right);
    }
};
```

**2. Hashing:**

```
template<class T>
struct Hash: ::std::unary_function<T, ::std::size_t> {
    ::std::size_t operator()(T const & value) const {
        ::boost::hash<T> hash;

        return hash(value);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Hash<T*> : ::std::unary_function<T*, ::std::size_t> {
    ::std::size_t operator()(T* const & value) const {
        Hash<T> hash;

        return hash(*value);
    }
};
```

So now I can continue using Boost's `hash_value` and it will not get masked for pointer types by Boost's default implementation (see **EDIT 3**).

**3. Example:**

In my application I have a thin wrapper for `unordered_set` which now looks like that:

```
template<class T, class H = Hash<T>, class E = Equal<T> >
class Set {
public:

// code omitted...

    bool contains(const T& element) const {
        return s_.find(element) != end();
    }

    bool insert(const T& element) {
        return s_.insert(element).second;
    }

// code omitted...

private:
    ::boost::unordered::unordered_set<T, H, E> s_;
};
```

So if we have some base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(const ::std::string& string) {
        if (string.empty())
            throw ::std::invalid_argument("String is empty.");

        string_ = string;
    }

    virtual ~Base() {
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Base& right, const Base& left) {
        return typeid(right) == typeid(left) && right.string_ == left.string_;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const Base& right, const Base& left) {
        return !(right == left);
    }

    friend ::std::size_t hash_value(Base const& base) {
        ::boost::hash<std::string> hash;

        return hash(base.string_);
    }

    friend ::std::size_t hash_value(Base* const& base) {
        return hash_value(*base);
    }

private:
    ::std::string string_;
};
```

And some derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(const ::std::string& string) :
            Base(string) {
    }

    virtual ~Derived() {
    }
};
```

Then we can even use polymorphism (which was my primary intention BTW):

```
Derived d1("¯\_(ツ)_/¯");
Derived d2("¯\_(ツ)_/¯");

Set<Base*> set;

set.insert(&d1);

assert(set.contains(&d2));
```

Hope this helps. Any suggestions are welcome.