# Generic equivalent to std function objects

Tags: c++, templates, generics, boost, stl

Is there any function objects in the boost that are generic equivalents to the std::equal_to, std::greater etc. family of function objects?

Essentially, std::equal_to should become something like

```
struct generic_equal_to
{
    template <class T, class U>
    bool operator()(const T& t, const U& u) const
    {
        return t == u;
    }
};
```

I can see how the generic versions of std::plus etc. might be trickier due to issues with the return type (though the `decltype` can solve that). I can't see any possible reason why the std::equal_to function object itself should require a template argument, though.

Surely somewhere in boost or in the STL these versions exist? They are, of course, trivial to write, but I very much dislike duplicating library code, especially for something as apparently trivial as this.

**EDIT**:

As some context as to why I would want this instead of using lambdas, or another function-object generation method:

I was writing a generic `boost::fusion` sequence comparison function thusly:

```
template <class T>
bool sequence_equal(const T& left, const T& right)
{
    return fusion::all(
        fusion::zip(left, right),
        fusion::fused<generic_equal_to>());
}
```

Note the `fusion::fused<generic_equal_to>` part, which leads to the isse that you can't practically specify a `boost::lambda` or `boost::phoenix` function-object by type. I guess one solution might be decltype:

```
fusion::fused<decltype(_1 == _2)>()
```

That seems very awkward though, and might not even work, depending on how `boost::lambda` or `boost::phoenix` is implemented - I'm really not sure.

I know you can use `fusion::make_fused` to get around this whole issue, but then you have to instantiate the function object. The solution I thought of, then, would be a non-template `equal_to` struct - I called mine `generic_equal_to`.

I know it's a very trivial problem - after all, `make_fused(_1 == _2)` will probably inline down to much the same assembly as `fused<generic_equal_to>`. I just couldn't believe that there was no `generic_equal_to` function object in boost or in the STL anywhere, hence this question.

Comment: I think you mean `operator()(const T& t, const U& u)`

Comment: +1, but I don't think you'll find one that's supported. The problem is important (I just wrote this very code in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063037/unordered-set-storing-elements-as-pointers/10063081#10063081) yesterday), but it's not sexy enough to attract Boost devs, and `std::equal_to` isn't broken enough that the standardization committee will deprecate it.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling hah yep! Trying to write code without a computer to check my syntax *always* trips me up somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything quite as direct as you're asking for, but there are utilities that not only cover your use-cases, but go beyond. They are [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/libs/lambda) and [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/phoenix/) (the latter being a more generic successor to the lambda library).

Example using Boost.Lambda for generic equality:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {};

bool operator==(foo, foo) { return true; }
bool operator==(foo, int) { return false; }

template <typename T, typename U, typename Func>
void f(const T& x, const U& y, Func func)
{
    std::cout << func(x, y) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda; // for placeholders
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    foo a, b;
    int i = 0;

    f(a, b, _1 == _2);
    f(a, i, _1 == _2);
}
```

And the same, with Phoenix:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {};

bool operator==(foo, foo) { return true; }
bool operator==(foo, int) { return false; }

template <typename T, typename U, typename Func>
void f(const T& x, const U& y, Func func)
{
    std::cout << func(x, y) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names; // for placeholders
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    foo a, b;
    int i = 0;

    f(a, b, arg1 == arg2);
    f(a, i, arg1 == arg2);
}
```

Each of these can be extended to support the other operators in the obvious way (and more generally, into other expressions). I would personally go with Phoenix, because if you find out you need more functionality than lambda offers you won't end up including both.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the other ways of generating function objects, but the whole point of my question was whether the trivial operations were already defined somewhere. They are, but they are all templacised on the `struct` instead of on the `operator()`.

Comment: Just added some rationale to why I was reluctant to use `boost::lambda` or `boost::phoenix`.

Comment: @Ayjay: Just use `make_fused`. They wouldn't manually implement the stdlib stuff if they already have utilities that do more.

Answer (score 1):

Now in C++14 there is `std::equal_to<void>` (that can be also used as `std::equal_to<>`)

> `std::equal_to<>` is a specialization of `std::equal_to` with parameter and return type deduced.

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) == std::forward<U>(rhs));
```

> Returns the result of equality comparison between lhs and rhs.

[Docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to_void)